# How to view docker image in localhost

Tags: docker

I'm trying to view a docker image in local host.
After running all the setup I run docker ps and get this:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                NAMES
73e73358ad00        talk-example_app     "./docker/php/init.sh"   17 hours ago        Created                   9000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9000->3000/tcp     dazzling_galois
66acb4dbebdf        nginx:latest         "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   17 hours ago        Up 17 hours               0.0.0.0:8111->80/tcp                 talk-example_nginx_1
e8cf5884ad4a        talk-example_app     "./docker/php/init.sh"   17 hours ago        Up 17 hours               9000/tcp                             talk-example_app_1
e34e2574db56        talk-example_redis   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   17 hours ago        Up 17 hours               0.0.0.0:63791->6379/tcp              talk-example_redis_1
ec44ad9b1c1f        mysql:5.7            "docker-entrypoint.s…"   17 hours ago        Up 17 hours               33060/tcp, 0.0.0.0:33061->3306/tcp   talk-example_database_1
```

I'm trying to run the image `talk_example_app`.  According to the documentation from this package I was simply supposed to clone the git repo, then run a command it would work.  I've tried several different docker commands that I read online and couldn't get any to work on localhost.

EDIT: [Documentation here](https://github.com/nahid/talk-example#installation)

How can achieve this?

Adding logs:

```
2019-09-13 17:01:27,528 INFO exited: talk-worker_01 (exit status 255; not expected)
2019-09-13 17:01:30,540 INFO spawned: 'talk-worker_02' with pid 31
2019-09-13 17:01:30,552 INFO spawned: 'talk-worker_00' with pid 32
2019-09-13 17:01:30,566 INFO spawned: 'talk-worker_01' with pid 33
2019-09-13 17:01:30,645 INFO exited: talk-worker_02 (exit status 255; not expected)
2019-09-13 17:01:30,657 INFO gave up: talk-worker_02 entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly
2019-09-13 17:01:30,664 INFO exited: talk-worker_00 (exit status 255; not expected)
```

Comment: Please link to the documentation so we can see what it says. What is this command that you are supposed to use?

Comment: Added the documentation link: https://github.com/nahid/talk-example#installation @KenY-N

Comment: `docker ps` lists the running containers. `talk-example_app_1` is a running container which is based on the image `talk-example_app`. Use `docker exec -it e8cf5884ad4a \bin\bash` to connect to your container.

Comment: @arun OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"binbash\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown

Answer (score 1):

The provided link suppose to run 4 containers.

- nginx,php,db and redis

From you `docker ps` Nginx is missing which is listening on port `8088`

run `docker ps -a` which will show stoped container you may see nginx there, check the logs of the Nginx why it stopped I assume the host `8088` may be occupied.

To check images run `docker images` and see images, for sure nginx will be exist.

you can check logs using

`docker logs`

or

`docker compose logs nginx`

Comment: Those were there running I didn’t include to keep code less.  With ngnix running then localhost:8088 doesn’t work.

Comment: without nginx you stack will not work. did you check the logs?

Comment: NgNix was running and it was on the list.  I didn’t include it to keep code minimal.